# less compiled failed with vue-cli

Tags: webpack, less, vue-cli

I import less in main.js but webpack compile failed.I dont understand this error message. I thought it is about path problem and tried both absolute path and relative path,but it does not work.

Here is Error message:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                      14:35:04

 error  in ./src/assets/style/index.less

Module build failed:

// load the styles
var content = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{\"minimize\":false,\"sourceMap\":
false}!../../../node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{\"sourceMap\":false}!./index.less");
          ^
Unrecognised input
      in /Users/yungcho/myWork/vo_reconstraction_front/src/assets/style/index.less (line 4, column 12)

 @ ./src/assets/style/index.less 4:14-285 18:2-22:4 19:20-291
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

Here is index.less

```
@import './variable.less';
@import './base.less';
```

webpack.base.conf.js

```
{
   test: /\.less/,
   use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'less-loader'
    ]
}
```

I'm appreciate if you can give me some suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this question. I use vue-cli and it has been configured for less support.If there is twice setting in webpack to one plugins,this error will be throwed.so you just to install less && less-loader

```
npm i less less-loader -D
```